# При попытке откомпелировать VS 2017 выдает: не удается открыть источник файл "stdio.h"

Tags: c++

```
код компиляции
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "stdio.h"  ConsoleApplication1 d:\Программа А\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\stdafx.h 10
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "tchar.h"  ConsoleApplication1 d:\Программа А\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\stdafx.h 11
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C1083   Не удается открыть файл включение: stdio.h: No such file or directory   ConsoleApplication1 d:\программа а\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\stdafx.h 10

Comment: Это стандартный проект, а что делать то?

Comment: А  `#include "stdafx.h"` Вы сами вставили или оно сгенерировалось?

Comment: @Rustam это стандартный непустой проект. При создании проекта нажимайте не Finish, а Next. Там будут опции проекта, где нужно поставить галочку Empty Project.